# Sort orders by status

Tags: mysql

I need to sort the table with the product_id that had the most status "FINISHED"

Table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE order2 (
  id         int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  status     enum('PENDING','FINISHED') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'PENDING',
  note       varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  client_id  int DEFAULT NULL,
  product_id int NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (id),  
  KEY fk_order_client2_idx (client_id),
  KEY fk_order_product2_idx (product_id),
  
  CONSTRAINT fk_order_client2  FOREIGN KEY (client_id)  REFERENCES client (id)  ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT fk_order_product2 FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES product (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

I tried a few ways but i didn't succeed...

---

My solution based on the response of the [@Tim Biegeleisen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73367757/9081629)

```sql
SELECT 
    COUNT(order2.product_id) AS total, order2.product_id
FROM
    order2
WHERE
    order2.status = 'FINISHED'
GROUP BY order2.product_id
ORDER BY COUNT(order2.product_id) DESC
```

Comment: Show us what you tried and what went wrong.

Comment: agreed, show what you have so far

Comment: Added in the topic the solution I got with the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some kind of aggregagion by product here.  Assuming you are using MySQL 8+, you may use `SUM()` as a window function:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM order2
ORDER BY SUM(status = 'FINISHED') OVER (PARTITION BY product_id) DESC;
```

On earlier versions of MySQL, you may use a join with aggregation approach:

```sql
SELECT o2a.*
FROM order2 o2a
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT product_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM order2
    WHERE status = 'FINISHED'
    GROUP BY product_id
) o2b
    ON o2b.product_id = o2a.product_id
ORDER BY
    COALESCE(o2b.cnt, 0) DESC;
```

Comment: Is there any way to group by the product_id ?

Comment: Check out my second query.

Comment: Sorry, had not appeared to me, I will check now

Answer (score 0):

give it a go, isn't order a word that should not by used for tables? not 100% sure:

```
    select * from order where status='FINISHED' order by product_id desc;
```

Comment: The table is in another language translated in this topic to facilitate understanding, your solution did not work it does not sort with orders that has more status "FINISHED"